# Is the offline store in qooxdoo compatible with all browsers and on local filesystem?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo, offlineapps, web-storage

I have a qooxdoo based application which runs from the local file system.

Now, I have seen that IE does not support offline store for local files in general (i.e . accessing the application with `file:///...`). But shouldn't qooxdoos offline store have a fallback for this scenario (e.g. userData behaviors)? I mean it is said to be compatible with all browsers, but it does not work in IE9...

And just for my interest: Does anyone know why IE does not support offline storage from local javascripts? Aren't local scripts more or about as trustworthy as remote ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the qooxdoo version you are using. The lastes 2.0.1 version e.g. does offer a fallback for older IE's to use userData in case the local storage is not supported [1]. As we use a feature check for deciding which implementation to use, it depends on IE if they are properly disabling the feature as soon as the API is not usable. If thats not the case, it might be a thing to consider to open up a bug report in qooxdoo's bugzilla [2] and report that as an issue.

- [1]
  https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/bom/Storage.js#L37
- [2] http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use version 2.0.1, but it's not working. Looks like IE doesn't want local scripts to store any data...

Comment: Looks like it is not possible at all for IE to store data in both, WebStorage and userData behavior, if the script is running from the local filesystem